# What is the equivalent of sweep on a rail in Rhino? Bevel is not working for me

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, extrude, bevel

I'm a jewelry designer and fairly new to Blender... This is my first time asking a question on the stack exchange.

I was trained in Rhino a few years ago and I remember the function "sweep on a rail" which is where you could take a shape / multiple shapes and apply them to your curve (for us jewelry designers, it was a cuff, wire collar, etc.)

I'm having trouble finding the equivalent to that function now. I feel like what I'm trying to do is pretty simple. I want to make an open metal collar (that opens on the front side of neck) that is a half circle tube where the flat side of circle touches your neck at one end then naturally twist 90 degrees to touch your collar bone on other end of necklace (see pic).

So far I've tried the bevel tool in the geometry section as well as a combo of array and curve but I can't seem to get it right.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm happy to share the file as well.

Thanks, 
Jessie
[image][image]

I tried Craig's advice, but this is what's happening now. For some reason the circle the wrong way so it's flat instead of a tube around the curve (collar). Here are some pics.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

### Final:

[image: Final]

### Steps:

**Bevel object.**

This will be our shape (profile) needed for beveling main neckles.

You can create it from **Add** > **Curve** > **Circle** and:

1. Rotate it on X axis by 90 degrees.
2. Go to **Front Ortho** view.
3. Select half of it.
4. Press <kbd>V</kbd> and select **Vector**.
5. Move middle point to be even with top/bottom ones (you can use **Snap to Vertices**).
6. Go to **Object Mode**.
7. Scale it down a little.

[image: steps1]

> Note: It's important to have this shape properly rotated before
>   Beveling another Curve.

**Main object.**

1. Create another **Curve > Circle**.
2. Go to **Object Data** tab.
3. Choose **Bevel Object** we have created earlier.
4. Check **Fill Caps**.
5. Uncheck **Cyclic**.
6. Position **Bezier Points** as you need.

[image]

Comment: Luke! This is awesome, thank you so so much! I'm trying this now. Thanks again, Jessie

Comment: @JessieDugan I've skipped some basic steps like Snapping and manipulating points, If you will have more question just ask ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Bevel Object function in Curve properties panel - add a curve circle and it will form a tube around your curve object. In edit mode of your bevel object, duplicate it and then you will see the curve is made of multiple tubes.
[image: bevel object]

Comment: Hi Craig, thank you for your help. I'm running into a new problem when I do this. My tube is flat when I add the full circle to the curve using the bevel tool. Any thoughts why this is happening? I'll attach screen shot now. Thanks.

Comment: Craig, I figured it out. I started with a full circle shape then deleted the 1/4 of it for the open part. Thanks for your help. I'll post the final result soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **precise** solution that also has the 90° rotation setup properly.

1. You need a (default) **straight path** with Bevel Object.
2. Select (one) end point, turn on proportional editing and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> 90°. (Linear falloff and, when using a default path, Proportional Size needs to be 4.)
3. Now select **second curve**, the one you really want to sweep along, and run this [script](http://community.cgcookie.com/t/how-to-find-out-the-length-of-a-path/1501/3) in Editor. A window will show the length.
4. **Straight path** now gets this length as X dimension (the "4" is replaced...) and apply scale (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
5. Add Curve Modifier to **straight path** using **second curve** as object.
6. Finally, **second curve**'s origin needs to be set to one of the **straight curve**'s end points.